# Is it possible to delete rows of an output file?

Tags: python

I am running beautiful soup in python to parse an html page. I have successfully extracted the info I want from the page. However, I now need to amend the output file, i.e. delete rows if values in a column do not exist.

Is it possible to do this in python, or should I just run a VBA macro over this in Excel to complete the task?

I have used f.write to populate my csv file:
`f.write(tag + "," + tag_span + "," + final_link + "\n")`

Before I close the file using `f.close()`, can I run a further loop to say e.g. delete all rows where `tag_span` is blank?

I am a complete newbie. If I wrote a more elegant script, I'm sure I'd be able to do this within my main loop - however I've been trying to get the desired output for several days now, and I'm keen to move to the next part of my project!

Comment: You're doubling your work by writing the file then rechecking the file. It's like putting all your plates in the cupboard THEN checking if they're washed and clean. Check if they're washed and clean BEFORE putting them in the cupboard. @kwinkunks has the perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe do something like this in your main loop?

```
if tag_span:
    f.write(tag + "," + tag_span + "," + final_link + "\n")
```

The code in the `if` loop will not run if `tag_span` is an empty string.

Alternatively, to check that all of those elements exist:

```
if tag and tag_span and final_link:
    f.write(tag + "," + tag_span + "," + final_link + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! The solution I was proposing to edit the final output file is as a result of final_link being a multi line value, so when outputted it messes with the neat 1 row per iteration of a csv. So to clarify, I know that every iteration will always have a value assigned to it, but when it parses "final_link" it unfortunately is not combining the value into one column/one cell, but several. Maybe this is the question I should have posed!

Comment: I see; by all means post another question. Some advice though... CSV can be a tricky format to write. It's probably not a bad idea to get your data into some kind of data structure (like a dictionary or a `pandas` DataFrame), then use [the `csv` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) or `pandas.to_csv()` to write the CSV. As you say, multi-line values are not allowed _per se_, but you can wrap them in quotes to allow "any" content. You don't want to be doing that yourself though.